# Taylor series centered at $ z_0= 0$ of the function $f(z) = \sin(z^2)$.

Tags: taylor-expansion

Find the Taylor series centered at $ z_0= 0$ of the function $f(z) = \sin(z^2)$.

Solution:
$z$ is replaced by $z^2$ in the well-known expansion

$$ \sin z =
\sum_{n=0}^{ +\infty}\frac{(-1)^nz^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\qquad ( \forall z \in \mathbb C). $$ Thus,
$$ f(z) = \sin (z^2) = \sum_{n=0}^{ +\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(z^2)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}=\sum_{n=0}^{ +\infty}\frac{(-1)^nz^{4n+2}}{(2n+1)!} \qquad( \forall z \in \mathbb C). $$ Is this correct?
I leave the exercise until there? If the procedure is wrong or if you have to continue developing, I hope you can help me.

Comment: It is correct, well done.

Comment: Your answer is correct, congrats!